# How to display imagese which are inside the json array in windows phone7/8? which include async Task in a list box

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, url, windows-phone-8

In windows Phone application i know how to display images forma  json data..

Regarding that i followed many articles on parsing the json data..

on the every article they have images in this way

```
"images" : "http://thegraphicsfairy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Stock-Image-Bird-Branch-GraphicsFairy1.jpg"
```

But i have Json Data like

```
"images" : [
    "http://thegraphicsfairy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Stock-Image-Bird-Branch-GraphicsFairy1.jpg"
    ]
```

like that i have many images in my JSON data

```
"flick" : ["http://thegraphicsfairy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/House-Painter-Man-Image-GraphicsFairy1.jpg"
]

"title" : ["http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/11/17/56749/google-docs-revision.jpg%3Ft%3D20111117074048"
]
```

So am unable to Parse them i tried with `{get,set}`

and i followed many articles like

[1. Facebook graph.](http://www.dfg-team.com/json-feeds-on-windows-phone/)

[2. Facebook Feed.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/06/23/10425845.aspx)

[3. Josn list box](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/working-with-json-web-services-in-silverlight-and-windows-phone-7/)

[4. Nokia Flicker](http://www.dfg-team.com/json-feeds-on-windows-phone/?lang=en)

I want to display them in a **Async List Box view**

and one more thing i stopped at starting Because in every json data  it starts with a JSON Object,.. But MY json data srats with JSON Array inside JSON OBJecet.. aganin Repeat...

This is my JSON data..  *and i am getting this data from a server so i may not change the Server*

```
{
"rC": "success",
"SpData": {
    "results": [
        {
            "ndetails": [
                {
                    "laoffers": [],
                    "offers_count": 0,
                    "sku": "3246",
                    "url": "http://www.google.com"
                },
                {
                    "laoffers": [
                        {
                            "id": "0c4ggUUkY8",
                            "price": "313.56",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "5OhvKwkQ",
                            "price": "311.95",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        }
                    ],
                    "offers_count": 2,
                    "name": "abc.com",
                    "url": "http://www.bing.com"
                },
                {
                    "laoffers": [
                        {
                            "id": "0bZw4cCK",
                            "price": "339.99",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "CwEEA",
                            "shipping": "8.17",
                            "price": "299.99",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        }
                    ],
                    "o_count": 2,
                    "name": "aaaa.com",
                    "recentoffers_count": 1,
                    "sku": "8567757",
                    "url": "http://www.avcd.com"
                }
            ],
            "model": "818BLK",
            "weight": "394625.36",
            "price_currency": "USD",
            "gtins": [
                "044558"
            ],
            "cat_id": "23042",
            "features": {
                "Condition": "New",
                "RAM - Memory": "2 GB - DDR3L SDRAM",
                "Rear-facing Camera - Camera": "5 Megapixel"
            },
            "length": "215.90",
            "created_at": 132657,
            "variation_id": "2SKEFyM",
            "geo": [
                "usa"
            ],
            "width": "130.05",
            "upc": "84884848",
            "ean": "47444",
            "category": "Tablets",
            "price": "334.99",
            "updated_at": 1391388552,
            "color": "Black",
            "manufacturer": "abc ,amifracture",
            "images_total": 1,
            "images": [
                "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AwTiVBnB_e4/T7-Wf4Z9HqI/AAAAAAAAACA/DA2UuBQsQ9g/s1600/funny-animal-pic-images-photos-02.jpg"
            ],
            "brand": "ccc",
            "sem3_id": "0iVcESQOy",
            "offers_total": 169
        }
    ],
    "total_results_count": 1,
    "results_count": 1,
    "code": "OK",
    "offset": 0
  }
  }
```

While Parsing at starting i failed Because.. in graph.facebook.com
thy have only two Json arrays..
But i have Json array Inside the Json object or JOSN object inside the json arrya..
and all the images are inside the json array which is inside the results which is inside a empty json object, and that is inside a JSOn array..

i am unable to parse some fields at starting.. and images are inside the json array are not displaying...

So i want to Parse JSON plus images By any json parsing methoid in C#(windows phone)..

and i want to deserilize the data including Images..

like this for example..

```
private void jsonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
string fbURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/microsoft";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (sndr, eArgs) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eArgs.Result))
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyPageObject>(eArgs.Result);
        this.jAbout.Text = json.about;
        this.jCategory.Text = json.category_list[0].name;

        this.jFounded.Text = json.founded;
        this.jWebsite.Content = json.website;
        this.jWebsite.NavigateUri = new Uri(json.website, UriKind.Absolute);
        this.jAddress.Text = json.location.street + ", " + json.location.city + ", " + json.location.state;
        this.jLikes.Text = json.likes.ToString();

        // download cover image
        string imageSource = json.cover.source;
        this.CoverImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageSource, UriKind.Absolute));
    }
  };
  webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(fbURL, UriKind.Absolute));
  }
```

At here they have image as normal way.. But i have image inside a JSON array..
and They used Root Object at starting Because they have only one Main JSON arrya.. But i have a many Json arrays and Objects which means `[{ or { some data [{ some data...` Like that i have..
And at here i want the out put exact like Nokia flicker.... But over there They parsed XML json data.. But i want ONly for JSON data..

Comment: I think there is no Problem with Image loader class.. and You said that your json data has a lot of josn objects.. over here You need to Parse spdata, results ,ndetails and laoffers and mainly images.. these are Main parts of  your JSON data and application.. and at here image Loader is working you need to diclare(parse) objects (image url) inside the array..

Comment: Yes Madhu sir,,.. But I want to Parse them and display them thats all. and thaks for understanding my question.. fastly..

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://json2csharp.com/) is a link that convert a json string to respective c# class architecture. Below is the class architecture of your json string.

```
public class Ndetail
{
    public List<object> laoffers { get; set; }
    public int offers_count { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int? o_count { get; set; }
    public int? recentoffers_count { get; set; }
}

public class Features
{
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__RAM - Memory { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__Rear-facing Camera - Camera { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Ndetail> ndetails { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string weight { get; set; }
    public string price_currency { get; set; }
    public List<string> gtins { get; set; }
    public string cat_id { get; set; }
    public Features features { get; set; }
    public string length { get; set; }
    public int created_at { get; set; }
    public string variation_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> geo { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string upc { get; set; }
    public string ean { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public int updated_at { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int images_total { get; set; }
    public List<string> images { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string sem3_id { get; set; }
    public int offers_total { get; set; }
}

public class SpData
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public int total_results_count { get; set; }
    public int results_count { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string rC { get; set; }
    public SpData SpData { get; set; }
}
```

DataContractJsonSerializer useful with this class architecture to parse a json string.
        Below is the sample code.
// json parsing code.

```
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Your json string));
 DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
RootObject parsedData= dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as RootObject;

if(parsedData!=null)
{
MessageBox.Show(parsedData.SpData.results.First().ndetails.First().url.ToString());
}
```

Comment: @user3124880 Add the last four lines of Code wherever you are getting your Response Json String, then Debug and check what comes in parsedData Object. PS: Don't call me Sir :).

Comment: @user3124880 I Also made change in my ans Please check.

Comment: @user3124880 what is the result of MessageBox.Show(parsedData.SpData.results.First().ndetails.First().url.ToString()); when you debug. and don't use sir

Comment: k. Please Update the complete process sir.. i know till Root object.. But i am strucked at.. json array and json Objects.. i mean i have mainly.These fields and i want to initilize the inside contents of class.... "SpData": {... Please ckeck my update question questions...
    "results": [
        {
            "ndetails": [
                {
                    "laoffers": []